# Opening separated sessions of IE8 or chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

We have a website that has a common logon page. A user chooses which site they want to use when they login and that site opens and the user has access based on their security.

In IE6 and IE7 a user can open 2 instances of IE and logon to 2 different locations and they work independently.

Using IE 8 or even chrome if a user logs in to one site and then opens another instance and goes to the logon page the site loads the same application the user is already in. Is there a setting somewhere to open IE or Chrome sessions in a separated sandbox?

Even though i exampled chrome, our endusers who this fix are for are IE8...sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to create an private browsing session of IE 8. Then the user uses a link for normal IE 8 and then uses private browsing for the other session. However. If a third session is needed your sol...

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Chrome "Wrench" and open a new "Incognito" window. That won't share any of the cached data from the other sessions.

IE 8 probably has a similar feature.